# Data Source Propeties - Analysis Services Business Center

Tags: data

When I try to build rsds  file in Report Data Source it showing me an error. Nothing Error show on Test Connection. The Error shows only when I click a button OK.

[image]

> Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.SharePointException: Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Adres URL "Dokument Power View/Z*******.rsds" jest nieprawidłowy. Może odnosić się do nieistniejącego pliku lub folderu albo do prawidłowego pliku lub folderu, który nie znajduje się w bieżącej sieci. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Adres URL "Dokument Power View/**********.rsds" jest nieprawidłowy. Może odnosić się do nieistniejącego pliku lub folderu albo do prawidłowego pliku lub folderu, który nie znajduje się w bieżącej sieci.